# Catch Failure on Time-Based Trigger (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that monitors a certain subset of folders. It records all files and their Last Edited Date and location in the subset. Then it sends out an email of all of the files that were recently edited, and a separate email of all of the files that haven't been touched in 3+ months. This is for managers in our company to have visibility of what's happening in those folders.

The issue: This script runs weekly on Mondays at 5 AM. About every other week, I'm getting a "Service error: Spreadsheets" on a line that's just  "sheet.appendRow(data)".

If I then go in and run it manually, it works fine.

Is there a way I can *catch* the error and rerun until successful?

Edit: Code

```
    function listFilesInFolderNew() {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      var parentFolder = getParentFolder();
      var parentFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(getParentFolderID());
      var level1Folders = parentFolderID.getFolders();
      var level1Files = parentFolderID.getFiles();
      var file;
      var allFolders;
      var subFolders;
      var subFileList;
      var data;
      var level2Files;
      var level2Folders;
      var level3Files;
      var level3Folders;
      var level4Files;
      var level4Folders;
      var folderArray;
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
      sheet.clear();
      sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date Created", "URL", "Last Updated",
                       "Parent Folder", "Last Updated By"
                      ]);
      // Every file in the folder containing this file.  
      // Level 1 ----------------- Files in Level 1
      var parentName = "";
      while (level1Files.hasNext()) {
        var level1File = level1Files.next();
        parentName = "";
        try {
          parentName = level1File.getParents()[0].getName();
        } catch (err) {}
        if (parentFolder != "Terminated Files") {
          data = [
            level1File.getName(), level1File.getDateCreated(),
            level1File.getUrl(), level1File.getLastUpdated(),
            parentFolder, Drive.Files.get(level1File.getId()).lastModifyingUser
            .displayName
          ];
          sheet.appendRow(data);
        }
      }
      // Level 1 ----------------- Folders in Level 1
      while (level1Folders.hasNext()) {
        var level1Folder = level1Folders.next();
        level2Folders = level1Folder.getFolders();
        level2Files = level1Folder.getFiles();
        // Level 2 ----------------- Folders in Level 2  
        while (level2Folders.hasNext()) {
          var level2Folder = level2Folders.next();
          level3Folders = level2Folder.getFolders();
          level3Files = level2Folder.getFiles();
          // Level 3 ----------------- Folders in Level 3  
          while (level3Folders.hasNext()) {
            var level3Folder = level3Folders.next();
            level4Folders = level3Folder.getFolders();
            level4Files = level3Folder.getFiles();
            // Level 4 ----------------- Files in Level 4  
            while (level4Files.hasNext()) {
              var level4File = level4Files.next();
              folderArray = [];
              parentName = level4File.getParents().next();
              try {
                while (parentName.getName() != "My Drive") {
                  folderArray.push(parentName.getName());
                  parentName = parentName.getParents().next();
                }
              } catch (err) {}
              if (folderArray[0] != "Terminated Files") {
                data = [
                  level4File.getName(), level4File.getDateCreated(),
                  level4File.getUrl(), level4File.getLastUpdated(),
                  folderArray[0], Drive.Files.get(level4File.getId())
                  .lastModifyingUser.displayName
                ];
                sheet.appendRow(data);
              }
            }
          }
          // Level 3 ----------------- Files in Level 3  
          while (level3Files.hasNext()) {
            var level3File = level3Files.next();
            folderArray = [];
            parentName = level3File.getParents().next();
            try {
              while (parentName.getName() != "My Drive") {
                folderArray.push(parentName.getName());
                parentName = parentName.getParents().next();
              }
            } catch (err) {}
            if (folderArray[0] != "Terminated Files") {
              data = [
                level3File.getName(), level3File.getDateCreated(),
                level3File.getUrl(), level3File.getLastUpdated(),
                folderArray[0], Drive.Files.get(level3File.getId())
                .lastModifyingUser.displayName
              ];
              sheet.appendRow(data);
            }
          }
        }
        // Level 2 ----------------- Files in Level 2  
        while (level2Files.hasNext()) {
          var level2File = level2Files.next();
          folderArray = [];
          parentName = level2File.getParents().next();
          try {
            while (parentName.getName() != "My Drive") {
              folderArray.push(parentName.getName());
              parentName = parentName.getParents().next();
            }
          } catch (err) {}
          if (folderArray[0] != "Terminated Files") {
            data = [
              level2File.getName(), level2File.getDateCreated(),
              level2File.getUrl(), level2File.getLastUpdated(),
              folderArray[0], Drive.Files.get(level2File.getId())
              .lastModifyingUser.displayName
            ];
            sheet.appendRow(data);
          }
        }
      }
      getAndSendEmails();
      var stop = new Date().getTime();
      var total = stop - start;
      total = total / 1000; //seconds
      total = total / 60; //minutes
      Logger.log("Start: " + start + "; Stop: " + stop + "; Total: " + total);
    }

    function getAndSendEmails() {
      //Get Emails
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");
      var Emails = "";
      var emailSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notifications");
      var dataRange = emailSheet.getRange("A2:A10");
      var dataEmail = dataRange.getValues();
      for (var i = 0; i < dataEmail.length; ++i) {
        var row = dataEmail[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        Emails = Emails + " " + emailAddress + ", ";
      }
      var timeCreated;
      var timeEdited;
      var d = new Date();
      var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
      oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
      var days90Ago = new Date();
      days90Ago.setDate(days90Ago.getDate() - 90);
      var changes =
          "<b>Recent Documents: (edited/created in last week) </b> <br><table><tr><td style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Document/Link</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Date Edited Last</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Last Edited By</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Manager / Containing Folder</b></td></tr>";
      var changesNOCHANGE =
          "<b>Recent Documents: (edited/created in last week) </b> <br><table><tr><td style=\"border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Document/Link</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Date Edited Last</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Last Edited By</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Manager / Containing Folder</b></td></tr>";
      var stale =
          "<br><b>Stale Documents: (90+ days since edit)</b> <br><table><tr><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Document/Link</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Date Edited Last</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Last Edited By</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Manager / Containing Folder</b></td></tr>";
      var staleNOCHANGE =
          "<br><b>Stale Documents: (90+ days since edit)</b> <br><table><tr><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Document/Link</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Date Edited Last</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Last Edited By</b></td><td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><b>Manager / Containing Folder</b></td></tr>";
      timeCreated = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
      timeEdited = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
      var lastEditedBy = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
      var shortOneWeekAgo = oneWeekAgo.toString().substring(0, 15);
      var shortDays90Ago = days90Ago.toString().substring(0, 15);
      var timeCreatedValue;
      var timeEditedValue;
      var shortCreated;
      var shortEdited;
      var dateEditedString;
      // If file is edited or created in the last week, send email.
      for (var j = 2; j < sheet.getLastRow() + 1; j++) {
        timeCreatedValue = timeCreated[j - 2];
        timeEditedValue = new Date(timeEdited[j - 2]);
        shortCreated = timeCreatedValue.toString().substring(0, 15);
        shortEdited = timeEditedValue.toString().substring(0, 15);
        dateEditedString = timeEditedValue.toString();
        //    Logger.log("\n" + timeEditedValue + " = " + "\n" + oneWeekAgo);
        //    Logger.log("\n" + shortEdited + " = " + "\n" + shortOneWeekAgo);    
        if (timeCreatedValue >= oneWeekAgo || timeEditedValue >= oneWeekAgo) {
          changes = changes +
            "<tr> <td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a href=" +
              "\"" + sheet.getRange("C" + j).getValue() + "\"" + "> " +
                sheet.getRange("A" + j).getValue() + "</a></td>" +
                  "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" +
                    dateEditedString.substring(0, 24) + "</td>" +
                      "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" +
                        lastEditedBy + "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" + sheet.getRange(
                            "E" + j).getValue() + "</tr>";
        }
    //    if (timeEditedValue <= days90Ago) {
    //      Logger.log(timeEditedValue + " <= " + days90Ago);
    //    } else {
    //      Logger.log(timeEditedValue + " is not <= " + days90Ago);
    //    }
        if (timeEditedValue <= days90Ago) {
          dateEditedString = timeEditedValue.toString();
          stale = stale +
            "<tr> <td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\"><a href=" +
              "\"" + sheet.getRange("C" + j).getValue() + "\"" + "> " +
                sheet.getRange("A" + j).getValue() + "</a></td>" +
                  "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" +
                    dateEditedString.substring(0, 24) + "</td>" +
                      "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" +
                        lastEditedBy + "</td>" +
                          "<td style=\" border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">" + sheet.getRange(
                            "E" + j).getValue() + "</tr>";
        }
      }
      changes = changes + "</table>";
      changesNOCHANGE = changesNOCHANGE + "</table>";
      stale = stale + "</table>";
      staleNOCHANGE = staleNOCHANGE + "</table>";
      if (changes != changesNOCHANGE) {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: Emails,
          bcc: "my.email***",
          subject: "Weekly Log of Recent Documents in Folder",
          htmlBody: changes,
          name: "Folder Weekly Status"
        });
      }
      if (stale != staleNOCHANGE) {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: Emails,
          bcc: "my.email***",
          subject: "Weekly Log of Stale Documents in Folder",
          htmlBody: stale,
          name: "Folder Weekly Status"
        });
      }
    }

    function getParentFolder() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var SSID = ss.getId();
      var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(SSID);
      var folderinDrive = fileInDrive.getParents().next().getName();
      return folderinDrive;
    }

    function getParentFolderID() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var SSID = ss.getId();
      var fileInDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(SSID);
      var folderinDrive = fileInDrive.getParents().next().getId();
      return folderinDrive;
    }
    //function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    //  return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
    //}
```

Comment: could you perhaps show the script ?

Comment: It's a hefty script, but added.

Answer (score 1):

These fails do happen from time to time, usually not due to a coding issue at all.

Best not to try ad infinitum, but if you give yourself a budget of say `n` times a simple pattern might be...

```
var success, count = 0;
do {
    try {

        // whatever statement or block subject to the try
        sheet.appendRow(data);

        // last statement should confirm success
        success = true;

    } catch (err) {
        // Log error perhaps
    }
    count += 1;
} while (!success && count < 10);
```

It may well be that the fail you are getting may last longer than can be handled by this pattern, as an alternative, the `catch(err)` block could add another installable one-time trigger some minutes later.

Comment: If I was running a lighter script, I would definitely implement that. When it fails, it seems to try to run the entire script, and my run-time is about 4 minutes. Do you happen to know the overhead of entering a Try-Catch block? If I implemented this on the lowest level, and it was successful, how much time would be added (in theory)?

Comment: try…catch certainly adds runtime time when in debugger, but it tends not to affect standard running. In this instance you would definitely benefit from writing all the results into a 2D array and then write that to the Sheet at the end in one write - this will reduce you run-time A LOT.

Comment: Okay, *how* should I be doing that? There's no appendRows() function. Without just making a loop and appending them all with appendRow() (not really much better), what's the ticket?

Comment: I used an array, then used this:

`var lastRowAndOne = sheet.getLastRow()+1;`        

`var appendRange = sheet.getRange(lastRowAndOne, 1, appendRowArray.length, appendRowArray[0].length);`     

`appendRange.setValues(appendRowArray);`

Sorry about formatting...

Comment: Adding values to a range beyond the last row always adds enough rows.

Comment: if my answer helped, feel free to accept it / vote, ta.

Comment: Sorry Jonathon, your answer helped (but I can't give it an upvote, due to reputation), but it wasn't a solution to my problem, either.